# How to show locations of all landmarks on a table next to your Google map?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the locations of all landmarks which I clicked, on a table next to my map like the following sample [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aacpb.png)

I don't want to show all the details. I just want to show the latitude and longitude  of the marker which appear when I clicked a place on the map. Here is my code (I want to show  latitude and longitude in a table instead of showing them in `infoWindow`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>

<script>
    function myMap() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
        var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(6.8210555, 80.0405499);
        var mapOptions = { center: myCenter, zoom: 12 };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
            placeMarker(map, event.latLng);
        });
    }

    function placeMarker(map, location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map, animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() + '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng()
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6ocynS4HxsKTgJu-8sq9uMqSBFafAhsg&callback=myMap"></script>

<center>
    <h4>
        <a href="secondQuestion.html">Go to the answer of 4th Question</a>
    </h4>
</center>
<br />
<center>
    <h4>
        <a href="HtmlPage1.html">Go to the answer of 3rd Question</a>
    </h4>
</center>
```

How can I do that by editing this code?

Comment: You are setting `'Latitude: ' + location.lat() + '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng()` as the infowindow content. So instead, just use this to set the content of your HTML element. I don't see any table in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lat</th>
            <th>Lng</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="info">

    </tbody>
</table>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    function myMap() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
        var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(6.8210555, 80.0405499);
        var mapOptions = { center: myCenter, zoom: 12 };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
            placeMarker(map, event.latLng);
        });
    }

    function placeMarker(map, location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map, animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });

        $('#info').append('<tr><td>'+location.lat()+'</td><td>'+location.lng()+'</td></tr>');

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() + '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng()
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6ocynS4HxsKTgJu-8sq9uMqSBFafAhsg&callback=myMap"></script>

<center>
    <h4>
        <a href="secondQuestion.html">Go to the answer of 4th Question</a>
    </h4>
</center>
<br />
<center>
    <h4>
        <a href="HtmlPage1.html">Go to the answer of 3rd Question</a>
    </h4>
</center>
```